# Use a JavaScript variable inside src of script tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, attributes, embed

Google provides its script embed code to display a trends Map by placing this code in our site.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.google.com.pk/trends/embed.js?hl=en-US&q=iphone&cmpt=q&content=1&cid=TIMESERIES_GRAPH_0&export=5&w=500&h=330"></script>
```

The above code displays the trends map.

Notice the `q=iphone` in the above URL. I want to pass a JavaScript variable value instead of hard coding a fixed value like iPhone in this case.

How can I use a JavaScript variable inside the src of script tag?

I tried creating script programmatically, it injects the script code but the script does not get executed.

My try

`document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('script')).src= varHavingScriptURL;`

My try [is in a JS Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Vp9Re/).

Comment: Show us the code you have for creating script programmatically

Comment: `Jsfiddle or demo would be helpful` ... yes, you are right, so show it to us :-)

Comment: using the `getScript` method of jQuery lets you do that very easily. have you tried it ?

Comment: @Adil I have added the code and the JSfiddle in the question of what I have tried.

Comment: Check the answer by @epascarello, put that code in script tags in the head tag of page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally after hours of struggle, I found the solution using PostScribe.

```
 // jQuery used as an example of delaying until load.


$(function
 () {
// Build url params and make the ad call
  var str= "magic";
postscribe('#ad', '<script src=//www.google.com.pk/trends/embed.js?hl=en-US&q='+str+'&cmpt=q&content=1&cid=TIMESERIES_GRAPH_0&export=5&w=500&h=330><\/script>');


});
```

[Postscribe](https://github.com/krux/postscribe)

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Znpxv/27/)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, you can not do this after page load. Look at the source of the script

```
document.write('<iframe width="500" ... </iframe>');
```

So you need to do this as the page is rendering because of the `document.write`.

Now looking at what you did

```
document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('script')).src = varHavingScriptURL;
```

That is not going to work, you need to break it up

```
var scr = document.createElement('script');
scr.src = varHavingScriptURL;
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(scr);
```

but again, it is not going to work because of the document.write.

Comment: How can I do this while the page is rendering ? A Fiddle would be helpful.